# A guess on the bound of the product of bounded sequence $\{x_{k}\}$ with $\lim_{t\to\infty}\prod_{k=0}^{t}(1-x_{k})=0$ exponentially.

Tags: convergence-divergence, infinite-product, upper-lower-bounds

Let $\{x_{k}\}$ be a bounded sequence, i.e., $|x_{k}|\le T$ for some positive constant $T$. Also, $x_{k}\neq 1$ and $x_{k}\neq 0$. If
\begin{align*}
 \lim_{t\to \infty}\prod_{k=0}^{t}(1-x_{k})=0
\end{align*} 
exponentially(at a rate of expoential decaying).

The question is can we find a positive constant $c$ relies only on $T$, such that
\begin{align*}
 \prod_{k=0}^{t}x_{k}\le \alpha|x_{0}|c^{t}
\end{align*}
for some positive constant $\alpha$？

My initial thoughts:

As pointed out by @C Monsour, we can construct $x_{k}$ to be such that 
\begin{align}
   x_{k}=&T, ~~\text{if}~~~ k ~~~\text{is even};\\
x_{k}=&\frac{T-1}{T}, ~~\text{if}~~~ k ~~~\text{is odd}.
\end{align}
Thus,  we have 
\begin{align}
|(1-x_{k})(1-x_{k+1})|=|\frac{1-T}{T}|<1.
\end{align}
Then, for every even $t$,
\begin{align*}
 \prod_{k=0}^{t}x_{k}=&x_{0}(T\frac{T-1}{T})^{0.5t}\\
=&x_{0}\sqrt{T-1}^{t}\\
\le&\alpha|x_{0}| c^{t},
\end{align*}
where $\alpha=1$ and $c=\sqrt{T-1}$.

Can we make the hypothesis that the value of $c$ depends only on the bound of $x_{k}$, i.e., only depends on $T$?

Comment: You want $c$ independent of $(x_k)$ and $\alpha$ dependent on $(x_k)$?

Comment: I hope to find $c$ dependent on $T$ while $\alpha$ is independent on $(x_{k})$. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm... several crucial hypotheses were just (silently) added to the question. Sure this is the final version?

Comment: Sorry about the changes. I am not good at formulating a problem. I think this is the last version.

Comment: I think the precise form of the "rate of convergence" condition is at least half the answer.

Comment: The 'rate of convergence' condition is that, there exists two positive constants $\alpha_{0}$ and $\lambda_{0}\in(0, 1)$ such that $lim_{t\to\infty}\prod_{k=0}^{t}(1-x_{k})\le \alpha_{1}\lambda^{t}$ for all non-negative $t$.